# Running a snap installed side-by-side/parallel to a Debian package?

Tags: snap

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04, and the default VLC here is:

```
$ vlc --version
VLC media player 3.0.4 Vetinari (revision 3.0.4-0-gf615db6332)
...
$ which vlc
/usr/bin/vlc
```

I want to keep this version, and then try out a nightly via `snap`. So I tried:

```
$ sudo snap install --channel=edge vlc
vlc (edge) 4.0.0-dev-5939-gee31d91 from VideoLAN✓ installed
$ snap list 
Name                  Version                  Rev   Tracking  Publisher    Notes
core                  16-2.36.3                6130  stable    canonical✓   core
...
vlc                   4.0.0-dev-5939-gee31d91  767   edge      videolan✓    -
```

Now I know I have this dev version of `vlc` installed, and it is in my system here:

```
$ ls -la /snap/bin/
total 8
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jan  4 09:25 .
drwxr-xr-x 13 root root 4096 Jan  4 09:25 ..
...
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   13 Jan  4 09:25 vlc -> /usr/bin/snap
```

But `/snap/bin/vlc` is a symlink (apparently) to `/usr/bin/snap`, so when I run it:

```
$ /snap/bin/vlc 
cannot change current working directory to the original directory: No such file or directory
```

So when I type `vlc`, I still get the old Debian version, which is how I want it.

But how do I run the `snap` version of VLC in this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following command to start the snap version of vlc is easier to remember. Open the terminal and type:

```
snap run vlc
```

`snap run <snap-package>` also works with all snap packages generally.

Comment: Thanks @karel - it indeed is easier with `snap run vlc`, especially since I don't have to change directory to `~` to run it; however, just to note, even with this method, snap vlc again cannot see files in `/tmp`.

Answer (score 3):

Found the answer, via:

cannot change current working directory to the original directory: No such file or directory · Issue #5 · smoser/pdftk · GitHub
  https://github.com/smoser/pdftk/issues/5

> Snaps do not have access to all directories.
>   Try using pdftk from your home directory.

Right, so I did this:

```
$ cd ~
$ /snap/bin/vlc 
VLC media player 4.0.0-dev Otto Chriek (revision 4.0.0-dev-5939-gee31d91)
[00000000023c93b0] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
...
```

... and now it runs... except it *really* cannot access many directories - it can't even list videos I have in `/tmp`, so now I have to symlink them to `~`

... except symlink from `/tmp` to `~/` is not visible by `snap` VLC either, so now I have to *copy* those files...